# GitHub: Как сделать Rebase and merge вместо Squash and merge

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase

Сделал **pull request** из своей ветки в **main**, 
чтобы смержить предлагает разрешить конфлиты и сделать `Squash and merge`,
но в таком случае не будет виден ежедневный прогресс и тонны коммитов - 
все просто соберется в один.

Думаю, дело в том, что моя ветка кроме

```
80 commits ahead
```

еще и

```
1 commit behind main
```

Как мне подтянуть то одно изменение и потом запушить с возможностью сделать `rebase` или обычный `merge`.

Если я в своей ветке делаю

```
git pull
```

то говорит:

```
main -> origin/main  
Already up to date.
```

Comment: Разве на гитхабе нет выпадающего списка, что делать с ПР? Там на выбор есть и "rebase and merge".

Comment: Все нормально, rebase был не доступен из-за конфликтов (которые разрешил), сделал merge, коммиты добавились. Вопрос решился сам собой